# Downloading JavaScript-loaded audio using Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script to automate the downloading of english audio files from a website, using Python.

The audio plays/loads on click, but I don't know how to "capture" the file as it loads and download it. I don't know javascript language.

The website: https://context.reverso.net/traduzione/inglese-italiano/pull+the+rug

For example, the first play button:

```
<button data-id="OPENSUBTITLES-2018.EN-IT_13515521" class="voice icon 
stopped" title="Pronuncia" data-lang="en"></button>
```

loads this URL:

https://voice2.reverso.net/RestPronunciation.svc/v1/output=json/GetVoiceStream/voiceName=Heather22k?inputText=cHVsbCB0aGUgcnVnCgoKWW91IGp1c3QgbGV0IGhlciBrbm93IHRoYXQgeW91IGNhbiBwdWxsIHRoZSBydWcu

Copying that into the browser, an audio file loads that can be downloaded manually. I want to download it automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: I've already tried selenium, but i cannot get over the java-loaded code on button click. Moreover i'd rather not use selenium because this code have to be executed on mobile kivy.

Comment: Do you know what the url is going to be?

Comment: @SuperStew thanks for your time . i have decrypted the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. The url inputText is generated encoding in base64 the written translation.

Comment: aww i spent time to figure it out as well but you beat me to it! ```https://voice2.reverso.net/RestPronunciation.svc/v1/output=json/GetVoiceStream/voiceName=[language Code from the .js file]?inputText=[text In Base64]```

Comment: @Xosrov thanks for your time.  Next time will be your turn 

Comment: How'd you stumble onto the base64?

Comment: @SuperStew Searching for keyword 'audio' i found this request function in js file:
audio.src = urls.reverso.voice + "/v1/output\x3djson/GetVoiceStream/voiceName\x3d" + languages.voice_codes[c] + "?inputText\x3d" + encodeToBase64(a)